# Using linux object files on Windows

Tags: c, build, makefile

I got the main.o, books.o, books.h, and the Makefile. Everything was compiled on a Ubuntu, but my OS is a Windows 7 64bits. How can I run the program having those files with me? The programming language used is C.

I want to run an executable built in Linux on a Windows machine, since my partner gave me only those files (main.o, books.o, books.h, and the Makefile)

Comment: Do you mean you want to re-build on Windows from the source files? Or do you want to run an executable built in Linux on a Windows machines?

Comment: @AlanAu I want to run an executable built in Linux on a Windows machine, since my partner gave me only those files (main.o, books.o, books.h, and the Makefile)

Comment: You cannot run Linux executables on Windows, and you cannot create a Windows executable from object files compiled for Linux.  You will need the source code, and you'll need to compile the source code using a Windows compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get a virtual machine running linux to have these object files be useful on your machine. At that point the "your machine" part of it is a bit of a stretch, though.

I was going to suggest that if your partner's code were pure C (ie, no system calls) you'd be able to jury rig something, but you can't even do that (easily) - Windows and Linux use different 64-bit ABIs.

Answer (score -1):

so you can use a GNU emulator on windows.

As the files you have already compiled in Linux and you can compile them in windows, this is the method you can use.

Comment: MinGW is not a "GNU emulator", at least not by the normal meaning of "emulator".  It's a GNU development environment (compiler, assembler, linker, etc.) which runs on Windows.  It will not help you run a Linux executable on Windows, or build a Windows executable from object files created for Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Cygwin is a lovely way to run linux applications on windows, but if don't want something that comprehensive make has been ported to windows, you can find it at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

Comment: Cygwin will not "run Linux applications on Windows", if by "Linux applilcations" you mean executables that were created to run on GNU/Linux.  Cygwin is a POSIX development environment that allows you to compile POSIX programs from source so that they will run on Windows, without having to port them to the Windows API first.